# It is possible to move a keystore jks from locale machine to a remote server?

Tags: java, tomcat, https, keystore, jks

On my local machine, I created a keystore (jks file) to using ssl with Tomcat.
I got the certificate signed and I imported it into keystore.

Now, I want used this keystore on the remote server. I copied the jks file on the remote server, and added the confs in the server.xml file in the Tomcat to read the file.

When I launch the tomcat, I got the following exception :

```
Invalid keystore format
```

(both machine use windows, java 8, and tomcat 9)

My question is : it is theoretically possible to copy a keystore from a machine to another ?
Or this exception is caused by something else?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How did you copy ? Check with hash if the files are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Of course is possible. Check that the .jks Keystore is OK. You can use KeyStore Explorer to inspect the jks.